# Find a variable from a variable value in C

Tags: c, variables, chess

I am trying to make a game similar to chess. I want the user to type in what position of the piece they want to move is, then were they want to move it... ( on an 8x8 grid - A1 through to H8)

I cant workout a simple way to find a variable from what the user has typed in. The code I currently have is:

```
void main() {

    printf("Enter Piece to Move: ");
    scanf("%s",&move);  

    printf("\n\nWhere would you like to move %s?:",move);
    scanf("%s",&to);

    [...]
```

What i also have is a variable list of all the location of pieces. What I would like to happen is, if the user was to enter A1 for the piece to move. I want the value of variable named A1 to be used. This is so I can have the current position of the piece and also what is in the place...

Hope this makes scene and someone can help :)

Comment: `main` should always have a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the concept of arrays. If you have a 2-dimensional array, you just need to convert the letter 'A' to a number and use it as in index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to a variable if you dynamically obtain its name. There's just no way to do it in C, unlike, say, PHP.

You should do the mapping manually

```
int a[8][8];
char c1, c2;
scanf("%c%c", &c1, &c2);
a[c1-'a'][c2-'1'] = ???; //this is your variable
```

The above is almost a pseudocode. I mean, you should take care of bad inputs and many other things, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible in C. When your program is running the names of the variables don't exist anymore, they only exist in your code.

Instead you should be using something called an array. It would take far too long to explain here, I think you should read a book on C.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 2 "holders" of your data, a board representation AND pieces positions like

```
enum {WKING=1,BKING,WPAWN,BPAWN,WQUEEN,BQUEEN,WBISHOP,BBISHOP,WKNIGHT,BKNIGHT,WROOK,BROOK};
int board[8*8];
/* positions: */
int wking,wqueen[9],wbishop[10],wknight[10],wrook[10],wpawn[8];
int sking,squeen[9],sbishop[10],sknight[10],srook[10],spawn[8];
...
setposFromTo(int piece,int from,int to) {
switch(piece) { case WKING: "set board AND position here" break; ... }}
```